# groupby roling get index of max value

Tags: pandas

```
       week_date    hy_code high
1630    2021-06-06  880324  871.76
1631    2021-06-06  880535  742.43
1632    2021-06-13  880324  860.31
1633    2021-06-13  880535  738.39
1634    2021-06-20  880324  842.46
1635    2021-06-20  880535  725.64
1636    2021-06-27  880324  836.14
1637    2021-06-27  880535  736.13
1638    2021-07-04  880324  836.05
1639    2021-07-04  880535  739.09
```

**Goal**

I want to get index of max value(base on last 3 rows) for each group and each row.

**Try**

```
df.groupby(['hy_code']).rolling(3)['high'].agg(lambda x:x.idxmax()).reset_index()
```

But the result does not match my expectation.

```
   hy_code  level_1 high
0   880324  1630    NaN
1   880324  1632    NaN
2   880324  1634    1630.0
3   880324  1636    1631.0
4   880324  1638    1632.0
5   880535  1631    NaN
6   880535  1633    NaN
7   880535  1635    1635.0
8   880535  1637    1636.0
9   880535  1639    1639.0
```

For `880535` group and `index=1637`,the index of max values based on last 3 rows should be 1633.

Answer (score 1):

I got different ouput, for easy check are data sorted by both columns and added to new column:

```
df['week_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['week_date'])

df = df.sort_values(['hy_code','week_date'])

df['new'] = (df.groupby(['hy_code'])['high'].rolling(3)
               .apply(lambda x:x.idxmax())
               .droplevel(0))

print (df)
      week_date  hy_code    high     new
1630 2021-06-06   880324  871.76     NaN
1632 2021-06-13   880324  860.31     NaN
1634 2021-06-20   880324  842.46  1630.0
1636 2021-06-27   880324  836.14  1632.0
1638 2021-07-04   880324  836.05  1634.0
1631 2021-06-06   880535  742.43     NaN
1633 2021-06-13   880535  738.39     NaN
1635 2021-06-20   880535  725.64  1631.0
1637 2021-06-27   880535  736.13  1633.0
1639 2021-07-04   880535  739.09  1639.0
```

Comment: my original dataframe is sorted week_date first. It's strange sorting hy_code first will get right answer.